# How to add multiple classes to a single JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

So I'm trying to add multiple classes to my JFrame 'frame' using a JPanel 'panel' but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's my main class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        panel.add (new Player()); // Class with paintComponent method.
        panel.add (new Terrain()); // Class with paintComponent method.

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Java Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (1000, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().add (panel);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the JFrame appears with a white background, but the paintComponent methods from the Player and Terrain classes aren't being called, so nothing else is being rendered. Is there anything wrong with this code? Thanks.

Edit: Here are my Player and Terrain classes:

Player:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings ("serial")
public class Player extends JComponent
{
    int x = 50;
    int y = 450;

    public void paintComponent (Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillRect (x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Terrain:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings ("serial")
public class Terrain extends JComponent
{
    Player playerClass = new Player();

    public void paintComponent (Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setColor (Color.GREEN);
        graphics.fillRect (0, 500, 1000, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You could be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread with long running or blocking code; You may not have overridden `getPreferredSize` of the `Player` or `Terrian` classes, causing them to be laid out with the default size of `0x0`; You could not be calling `super.paintComponent`, cause all sorts of weird painting issues; Would you like me to continue guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've failed to override `getPreferredSize` of `Player` and `Terrain`, causing them to be laid out at their default size of `0x0`
2. You've broken the paint chain by not calling `super.paintComponent`, which could cause no end of painting issues and artifacts
3. The reference of `Player` in `Terrain` has nothing to do with the reference on the screen

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: The reference of Player in Terrain is actually an artifact of something I was working on earlier. :P

Comment: Thanks for the info (again). I have added super.paintComponent and overriden getPrefferedSize to match my window size in both Player and Terrain. But now only the first class I added to my JPanel in Frame.java (in this case it would be Player) is rendered.

Comment: Yes, generally with FlowLayout, they get added side by side (try calling pack on the frame instead of setSize), instead, try adding player into terrain. BTW, I'd generally avoid component based entities and instead devise a concept if something that is paintable and paint them all within a single component

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing, yeah. Or something like that. I hope.